# Static methods and inheritance: why value of static property of one class goes to another?? 'get_called class'

Tags: php, inheritance, static-methods

I have a code:

```
<?php

abstract class Model
{
    static protected $_table;

    static public function setTable()
    {
        self::$_table = get_called_class();
    }

    static public function getTable()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$_table)) {
            self::setTable();
        }
        return self::$_table;
    }

}

class User extends Model {}
class Post extends Model {}

echo User::getTable();
echo "<br>";
echo Post::getTable();

?>
```

The output of echoing it, is: "User User". I can't understand it why value of property one's class go to another. Why doesn't second echo give 'Post' output? What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using static properties, after `Model::$_table` gets set the first time your class isn't going to set it again. Unless you change your `Model::getTable()` function so that it calls `self::setTable()` every time.

You could also create `Model` as a trait instead of a traditional class.

For example:

```
trait class Model
{
    static protected $_table;

    static public function setTable()
    {
        self::$_table = get_called_class();
    }

    static public function getTable()
    {
        if(!isset(self::$_table)) {
            self::setTable();
        }
        return self::$_table;
    }

}

class User {
    use Model;
}

class Post {
    use Model;
}

echo User::getTable();
echo "<br>";
echo Post::getTable();
```

Comment: Thanks, it explains a little bit. What I still can't understand why User and Post class have a common property instead of having individual value. I set User's table name, why then Post table is set as well? It's like there is only one static property $_table for every class inherting from Model class...

Comment: Static class properties behave differently than non-static class properties. Hence the name `static` these properties are persistent. You might want to look [at the example in the php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) Could help you restructure your current classes.